# Store binary data string into byte array using c#

Tags: c#, encoding, byte, arrays

I have a webservice that returns a binary data as a string. Using C# code how can I store it in byte array? Is this the right way?

```
System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(inputString);
```

Actually, this didn't work. Let me explain it more:
the web service code converts a string (containing XSLFO data) into byte array using utf8 encoding. In my web service response I only see data something like `"PGZvOnJvb3QgeG1sbnM6Zm89Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkvWFNML0Zvcm1hdCIgeG1sbnM­6eGY9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cuZWNyaW9uLmNvbS94Zi8xLjAiIHhtbG5zOm1zeHNsPSJ1c=="`. Actually I would like to have the original string value that was converted into byte[] in the service. Not sure if it possible?

Comment: yes, the code you posted is correct, assuming that the data is encoded using UTF8.

Comment: What format is the binary data in? Is it in Base64, UTF8 or what? The encoding matters.

Comment: @user465876: You said it was originally binary data... what kind? Treating (say) a picture as a UTF-8-encoded string is a bad idea.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, that's a bad idea.

Unless the input data was *originally* text, trying to use `Encoding` is a bad idea. The web service should be using something like base64 to encode it - at which point you can use [`Convert.FromBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) to get the original binary data back.

Basically, treating arbitrary binary data as if it were encoded text is a quick way to lose data. When you need to represent binary data in a string, you should use base64, hex or something similar.

This may mean you need to change the web service as well, of course - if it's creating the string by simply treating the binary data as UTF-8-encoded text, it's broken to start with.

Comment: Jon, my code above didn't work. Actually the web service code converts a string (containing XSLFO data) into byte array using utf8 encoding. In my web service response I only see data something like "PGZvOnJvb3QgeG1sbnM6Zm89Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkvWFNML0Zvcm1hdCIgeG1sbnM6eGY9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cuZWNyaW9uLmNvbS94Zi8xLjAiIHhtbG5zOm1zeHNsPSJ1c==". Actually I would like to have the original string value that was converted into byte[] in the service. Not sure if it possible?

Comment: @user465876: That looks like Base64 to me... so Convert.FromBase64String should be fine. But if it was *originally* a string, why was it converted into a byte array to start with?

Comment: It worked with Convert.FromBase64String. Actually same webservice is being called from different places and in most cases clients work with byte array.

Comment: See also [this Phil Haack blog post](http://feeds.haacked.com/~r/haacked/~3/5hyXGYRO0Bo/hazards-of-converting-binary-data-to-a-string.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If the string is encoded in UTF8 Encoding, then yes that is the correct way. If it is in Unicode it is very similar:

```
System.Text.Unicode encoding = new System.Text.Unicode();
byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(inputString);
```

Base64Encoding is a little different:

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(inputString);
```